# JQuery not working - rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I cannot get my jquery to work from the asset pipeline and I have tried a host of things to fix and nothing is working and I just can't seem to figure this out.  I have a simple jquery function for now to test it.  Note, it works when I put the jquery code in the HTML.

**app/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .


$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

</body>
```

**GemFile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pg',           '0.17.1'
gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'contact_us', '~> 1.0.1'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_security_extension'
gem 'stripe'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
  gem 'foreman'
end


group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'

end
```

**Config/development**

```
Rails.application.configure do

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  # Emailer.
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }  
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  port: 587,
  domain: ENV["HEROKU_DOMAIN"],
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"]
  }
  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true


  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Comment: Can you try one thing? Remove "require tree ." And put "require turbolinks" at the bottom.

Comment: thanks, Jagjot.  Just tried that, but it didn't work.  The fact that I can't get jquery to work is embarrassing.  Never happened in any other app for me.  Jquery code works when put into the html, but not in the application.js file.

Comment: Can you put this application in a repo and share the link? If this is possible. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your elements didn't appear on the page yet. So just simply wrap your actions in jQuery `document.ready` to wait them

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
   });
});
```

[Documentation: $( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: @richiepop2 I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

Check for the turbolinks load event like:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });

  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
})
```

Comment: thanks @neydriod.  When I added the load event, I still get no response.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Why don't you try to create a new file inside your `app/assets/javascripts` folder and put your code here? First lines of `application.js` say</strike>

---

```
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
```

---

Make sure your assets are recompiled on each request. <strike>If so, you should see a list of GET request to the server on each page load in the development.log</strike>

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by creating the corresponding .js.erb file for the html file mentioned above and add the jquery in that. For eg suppose the html is in index.html.erb, create index.js.erb and place the jquery in it.

index.js.erb:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
  $("p").hide();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
  $("p").show();
});
```

Then in application.js, append this:

```
$(function() {
 $.getScript("/<model name path>.js");
});
```

where you can place the model name path (for eg posts.js) in case your url is /posts for the index html page. I replicated all this in my system and its working here.

Comment: this is absurd. Why would you do this instead of just including a JavaScript file into your template?

Comment: pls explain what do you mean by "including a JavaScript file into your template"